# How to git pull without git add them

Tags: git, github

scenario: I have made some changes to my project and I don't want to `git add` them because those are not fully done. At the same time, I want to `git pull` some changes from the same branch. What should I do here

Comment: If you're going to experiment, make sure you have a backup of your local folder before you do. Have you tried stashing the files before pulling?

Comment: no. does stashing help me in this scenario

Comment: Remember that `git pull` is just a way to run two Git commands. The first one is `git fetch`, which you can always run any time. It's the *second* Git command that is problematic. That second command is `git merge` by default, but you can choose `git rebase` instead. Either one requires that your work-tree be clean to start with. You can use `git stash` to arrange for that, but if your plan is to use `git rebase`, I think it works much better if you just commit (learn to use `git rebase -i`, it's the way to go, you'll use it for a lot more than just bringing in others' commits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options.  Probably the simplest would be to stash your work:

```
git stash
```

This tells Git to make a commit (or two) of your working directory and stage.  After you have pulled the new changes, you may apply the stash via

```
git stash apply
```

Another option, perhaps a bit more sophisticated, would be to actually `git add` your changes and make a commit:

```
git add ...     # maybe multiple times
git commit -m 'your commit'
```

Then, do a pull rebase:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

This will bring in the new commit(s) *underneath* the commit you just made.  Finally, you may finish your work and then *amend* the temporary commit:

```
git commit --amend
```

One possible advantage of this second option is that it gives you the option to do a `git push` with all the work in the temporary commit.  If this work is very important, then protecting it via a backup may matter to you.  Doing a stash on the other hand just leaves you with a local commit only.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `git stash` is what you are looking for

From [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to follow

`git stash` //This will hide your new code changes
now you can do whatever you want.. like 
`git fetch`
or
`git pull`
or
`git reset`

once you have done the `git pull`, you can get the un-added files back by : 
`git stash apply`

**Note :** 
 Personally I do not prefer git pull and git merge. Rather than doing those, I follow below mentioned commands.
*I Do not use `git pull` / `git merge`, but use* : 
`git fetch origin` and then
`git rebase origin/master` *//or your reponame/branch*